# Получить значение одной переменной с PHP файла

Tags: php

имеется много php-скриптов. У каждом из них присутствует переменная ($desc) с описанием что за скрипт (что делает), а дальше идет код скрипта. Нужно пройтись по этим скриптам и вытянуть с них значения этой переменной. Как можно организовать?
Вариант с чтением всего содержимого и парсингом не подходит
Коды всех скриптов начинаются так:

```
<?php
$desc = 'Описание скрипта';

/* далее идет тело скрипта (логика, классы), возможны выводы: */
echo 'Здесь что-то выводится';
```

Сам `$desc` может быть записан в таких вариантах:

```
$desc = "";
$desc = <<<DESC

DESC;
```

Можно конечно читать построчно и парсить, но это похоже на какой-то костыль. Может есть другие варианты?

Comment: что представляет собой код скрипта? приведите пример файла вообще. И почему не подходит вариант с чтением и парсингом? в любом случае все файлы будут так или иначе открыты и прочитаны.

Comment: используйте [edit] для редактирования вопроса.

Comment: поправил. Суть в том, что в скрипте может быть куча логики с выводом чего-то, созданием объектов и т.п. И естественно для получения значения этой переменной засорять память неохота

Comment: Т.е. переменная еще может переопределяться?

Comment: действо одноразовое? Если выполнять файл не желательно, остается только читать и разбирать.

Comment: *это похоже на какой-то костыль* - какая задача, такое и решение. только это не костыль, а нормальное решение для больших файлов.

Comment: У вас все проблемы из-за кривой архитектуры. если приходится брать каждый файл и смотреть там - значит дело тут как раз в архитектуре. Вам нужно не думать как лучге получить значение деск из файла. а как можно упростить процесс поиска конкретного файла.

Comment: @teran пока товарищ не наткнется на конструкцию `$desc = getDesc()`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я так понимаю, цель только собрать `$desc` из начала файла. возможные переопределения не интересуют.

Comment: @Manitikyl дак вероятно там и суть работы этой, чтобы избавиться о такой проблемы и вынести эти описания в другие места и т.п. т.е вероятно человек рефакторинг провеодит какой-то

Comment: @teran вот в начале и будет вызов функции

Comment: Мне нужно пройтись по файлам и вывести значения этих "описаний" - сделать таблицу с двумя столбцами: 1) полный путь к файлу; 2) описание, которое хранится в переменной $desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не выполняя логику внутри файла, файл таки придётся парсить. Для этого в пыхе уже есть [готовый разбор на токены](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.token-get-all.php) и вам надо только перебрать их в поисках нужной переменной. Например, вот так:

```
$descList = [];
foreach (glob(__DIR__ . "/tmp.*.php") as $filename) {
    echo "{$filename}:\n";
    foreach (token_get_all(file_get_contents($filename)) as $token) {
        if (!is_array($token)) {
            continue;
        }
        echo "\t{$token[2]}: " . token_name($token[0]) . " ('{$token[1]}')\n";
        if ($token[0] === T_VARIABLE && $token[1] === '$desc') {
            $descList[$filename] = null;
            continue;
        }
        if ($token[0] === T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING && array_key_exists($filename, $descList)) {
            eval('$descList[$filename] = ' . $token[1] . ';');
            break;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($descList);
```

В результате получаем нечто вида:

```
array(2) {
  ["/foo/bar/baz/tmp.1.php"] => string(3) "foo"
  ["/foo/bar/baz/tmp.2.php"] => string(3) "bar"
}
```

При этом в самих файлах 1 и 2 у меня такой код:

```
<?php
exit;
$desc = "foo";
```

И

```
<?php
echo "!!!";
$desc = "bar";
```

Как видите нет никаких проверок достижения объявления переменной (в первом файле `exit` не даст переменной появиться если файл исполнить честно). Плюс нет никаких проверок на отсутствие синтаксических ошибок. И т.д. Но просто как пример сгодится. Если надо усложнять и проверять что-то, то дальше можете сами :)

Comment: Протестирую на скорость и отпишусь

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку:

> Если включение происходит внутри функции включающего файла, тогда весь
>   код, содержащийся во включаемом файле, будет вести себя так, как будто
>   он был определен внутри этой функции. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php

То получаем массив путей файлов и описаний следующим образом

```
$moduleNames = [
    '/a/a.php',
    '/b/b.php'
];

$modulesInfo = array_map(function($item) {
    include($item);
    return [
        'path' => $item,
        'desc' => $desc
    ];
}, $moduleNames);

print_r($modulesInfo);
```

Comment: А если в файле `'/a/a.php'` Есть `echo`? То на экране мы увидим и это `echo` и `print_r`? ну если нам никому не показывать, то пойдет, но вопрос 2ух дублирующий классов остается так-же непродуманным.

Comment: @Manitikyl куда печальнее будет когда в файле проводятся какие-то манипуляции с данными, чтение файлов и т.п.

Comment: ну echo решается перенаправлением в `/dev/null` и записью массива в отдельный файл

Comment: Если одноразовая операция, то можно в IDE запустить замену во всех файлах `$desc` на `return $desc`. И в коде уже юзать `$desc = include...`. Теоретически больше ничего в файле подгружаться не будет

Comment: Все варианты, где будет идти исполнение скрипта не подходят. Наверное остановлюсь на варианте построчного чтения и парсинга

Comment: Хммм... А если заменить `$desc = ` на `throw`? Тогда можно будет includить файлы, перехватывать исключения и подключать следующий файл)

Если, конечно, описание в самом верху файла)

Answer (score 0):

Ну если есть какой-то массив `$array` - со списком файлов (а это думаю вы реализовать сможете, тем более вопрос не в этом), то можно через буфер получать:

```
$array = [...];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $desc = NULL;

    ob_start();
    include($value);
    ob_end_clean();

    var_dump($desc);
}
```

**ВОЗМОЖНО** такой метод вам не подойдет, например если в файлах есть дубликаты классов (т.е. 2 файла создают один класс с одинаковым именем), тогда нужно будет создать "*условную песочницу*", реализация будет как-то так:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $desc = file_get_contents('/sandbox.php?file='.rawurlencode($value));
}
```

**Файл sandbox.php:**

```
$desc = NULL;
ob_start();
include(rawurldecode($_GET['file']));
ob_end_clean();

echo $desc;
```

---

Я только постарался передать идею, до совершенства доведете сами :)

Comment: писали же, что инклуд файлов не желателен.

Comment: @teran в чем проблема? В вопросе не увидел про инклуд...

Comment: @teran Если личная неприязнь к `include`, то можно через `require` :D

Comment: в комментариях обсуждали

Comment: include - это и есть чтение всего файла и оно не приемлемо. Выше в комментах уже упоминали что будет кака, если какой-то скрипт делает тяжелые операции

Comment: @SanyaH на сколько долгие? если операция разовая, то какая разница, даже если придется подождать минут 30?